# delete empty spaces of files python

Tags: python, file, spaces

I have a file with several lines, and some of them have empty spaces.

```
x=20
y=3
z = 1.5
v = 0.1
```

I want to delete those spaces and get each line into a dictionary, where the element before the '=' sign will be the key, and the element after the '=' sign will be its value.

However, my code is not working, at least the "delete empty spaces" part. Here's the code:

```
def copyFile(filename):
    """
    function's contract
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as inFile:
        for line in inFile:
            cleanedLine = line.strip()
            if cleanedLine:
                firstPart, secondPart = line.split('=')  
                dic[firstPart] = float(secondPart)
        inFile.close()
    return dic
```

After clearing the empty spaces, my file is supposed to get like this

```
x=20
y=3
z=1.5
v=0.1
```

But is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: will all the values on the right be valid Python literals? Strings, ints, etc..

Comment: yes, everything that the file has on the right is either ints or floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

For one, you never define `dic` so when you try to add keys to it you get a `NameError`.

Second, you don't need to `inFile.close()` because you're opening it in a `with` which will always close it outside the block.

Third, your function and variable names are not PEP8 standard.

Fourth, you need to `strip` each part.

Here's some code that works and looks nice:

```
def copy_file(filename):
    """
    function's contract
    """
    dic = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            cleaned_line = line.strip()
            if cleaned_line:
                first_part, second_part = line.split('=')
                dic[first_part.strip()] = float(second_part.strip())
    return dic
```

Comment: My dictionary is declared outside the function since it'll be used in other functions. Forgot to inform that in the post, my bad for that. Either way, the code is working thanks to you, thank you (and also thanks for the other tips!) !!

Answer (score 5):

You need to `strip` after splitting the string.  That's assuming that the only unwanted spaces are around the `=` or before or after the contents of the line.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def copyFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inFile:
        split_lines = (line.split('=', 1) for line in inFile)
        d = {key.strip(): literal_eval(value.strip()) for key, value in split_lines}
    return d
```

Comment: also strip value because indentation matters for eval `literal_eval(value.strip())`

Comment: also why not using dict comprehension syntax?

Comment: and `split_lines = map(str.strip,(line.split('=', 1) for line in inFile))` to avoid stripping key & value

Comment: That I don't follow.  Won't that try to `str.strip` a list?  `(map(str.strip, line.split('=', 1)) for line in inFile)` maybe, but that's a pretty busy line.

Comment: I ws trying a way to avoid applying strip on both key & values explicitly but it doesn"t matter

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. The reason you're not removing the white space is that you're calling `.strip()` on the entire line.  `strip()` removes white space at the *beginning* and *end* of the string, not in the middle.  Instead, called `.strip()` on `firstpart` and `lastpart`.
2. That will fix the in-memory dictionary that you're creating but it won't make any changes to the file since you're never writing to the file.  You'll want to create a *second* copy of the file into which you write your `strip()`ed values and then, at the end, replace the original file with the new file.

Answer (score 0):

to remove the whitespace try .replace(" ", "") instead of .strip()

Comment: when i print each line (after the .replace) to check if it deleted the empty spaces, it did (so thanks by that!), however when adding to the dictionary, the empty spaces "come back" lol

i can have "z=1.5" in the file after using the .replace, but it still adds "z " to the dictionary, instead of only "z"

Comment: that is because you are splitting the original line named 'line', try splitting cleaned_line     first_part, second_part = cleaned_line.split('=')